# Javascript selectionStart / selectionEnd Cross-Browser Issue

Tags: javascript

I am modifying Javascript masked input class to have it based on `oninput` method (to avoid `keydown`/`keyup` 0 & 229 issues on Mobile) and faced cross browser problems with `selectionStart` / `selectionEnd` properties - they return different indexes in:
    1) Desktop /Android Chrome 
    2) Android defaul internet browser
    3) LG SMART TV Browser (unknow type)

for example:

by entering `123`:

1) Deskntop browsers + Android Chrome return:

```
selectionStart / selectionEnd : 1/1
selectionStart / selectionEnd : 2/2
selectionStart / selectionEnd : 3/3
```

2) Android default browser

```
selectionStart / selectionEnd : 0/0
selectionStart / selectionEnd : 1/2
selectionStart / selectionEnd : 2/3
```

I do not understand what is wrong with these properties. They all are supported and fired in above browsers, so it is not cross browser issue (IE<8, `createTextRange()` etc), however they return different indexes.

Please help to normalize `selectionStart` / `selectionEnd`

Html:

```
<textarea id="Log" name="Log" cols="1" rows="10" class="Log" style="width:100%"></textarea>
<input type="text" name="SER" id="SER" />
```

Javascript:

```
var node = document.getElementById("SER");
node.oninput=function(){document.getElementById('Log').innerHTML+='selectionStart / selectionEnd:'+this.selectionStart + '/'+ this.selectionEnd+'\n';
```

};

JSFiddle
https://jsfiddle.net/cmpt/n5ffvvzt/

Comment: I'm having this same issue - very frustrating. Were you ever able to find a work-around?

Comment: same issue, can't find any work around yet on android.